# Post build in Jenkins with last parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to know if is possible to set a post build triggering the job with the last parameters. I've found this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin but I can't have a properly way to call, this plugin is based on last job index.

It's a short question but I was not able to find a properly fix / workaround for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must save this parameters in some file in workspace folder for example `settings.xml` or something similar, you can in easy way make command like this:

```
sh """echo '<name>$PARAMETER_VALUE</name>' >> ./settings.xml"""
```

When you would like to read this parameter you could use sed option or something else like:

```
sh """awk '{if($1 == "name") print $2}' ./settings.xml"""
```